# How to return my string after calling yield

Tags: return, yield

I wrote a labrad server. It works. But I ran into a problem.
First, it's my code:

```
from labrad.server import LabradServer, setting
import numpy as np

SERVERNAME = 'tian'

class Tian_Server(LabradServer):

    name = SERVERNAME

    def initServer(self):
        self.dac = self.client.servers['laserdac_server']

    def set_supervisor_current(self,first_current):
        self.dac.set_individual_analog_voltages([('05', first_current)])
        print 'supervisor is set to:',first_current

    # scan current
    @setting(1)
    def scan_supervisor_2Ddata(self,c):

       "some code"

        for v in scan1:
            yield self.dac.set_individual_analog_voltages([('05', v)])
            "take my data"
            print "scan supervisor: ", v

        "some code"
        return <my data as a 2D-string>


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from labrad import util
    server = Tian_Server()
    util.runServer( server )
```

I need to use yield, or I can not set current at the same time.
But now, I cannot return my data which should be used in other method.
Does anyone know it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Somehow, your question doesn't make sense, having a return statement next to a yield statement. Without a broader context, it is hard to tell, but it looks like you have a bit of an A/B problem, in that you just need to look at it from different angle and refactor things into separate functions.

Comment: Questions: what does set_individual_analog_voltages return? What is a 2D string? Which methods override base-class methods? What is `scan1` (i.e., where is it defined?)

Comment: Sorry to make things unclear. I solved it just now by writing all things in one method. I want to set one voltage (set_individual_analog_voltages, this method has no return, just set my system to one voltage) and take data, then set another voltage and take data.

Comment: Therefore my data is a 2-dimension string, the first index is for the voltage I set, the second index is the data I take at that voltage. But set voltage needs to connect another server, so I need to use yield, or it will run asynchronously. But then, I cannot return my data in this method...My question is that how to send my data to other methods in this class for use.